# using angular-ui-router in asp.net 5 mvc 6

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I have created a site using MVC6, AspNet5 and Angular. I use Angular specifically for a wizard. Now I want to use a multi-step wizard with angular-ui-router as described in [angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router). It seems the ui router only works when creating an SPA. I also cant get it to load a cshtml file as the wrapper. Any starting points=

Comment: I made a huge mistake. I added a folder Views in the wwwroot folder to serve my html templates for the ui-router. Views has a special meaning. Moving the html files to a new folder called static worked. Now I need to figure out how to hide the paths in the url as is done in the mentioned example

Answer (score 0):

If I think this true you tend to develop SPA and this target front-end html,css and angularJS you do not need .chtml unless you will return it first time or to return html via ajax call,
and for you wizard like form I think if you collect all your form data and send it to post method at server and process it post action.